# PySpark convert Unix epoch to "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" in UTC

Tags: pyspark, time, utc, epoch

I have a bigint column representing Unix epoch. I'd like to convert it to string of format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" in **UTC time**. I tried a few approaches but they all return local time not UTC time.

DataFrame `time_df`:

```
time_df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        (1651886168, ),
    ],
    ["epoch"]
)
```

```
root
 |-- epoch: long (nullable = true)

+----------+
|     epoch|
+----------+
|1651886168|
+----------+
```

In UTC `1651886168` is `2022-05-07 01:16:08`

Incorrect approach 1:

```
time_df.select('*', F.from_unixtime(F.col('epoch'))).show()

+----------+-----------------------------------------+
|     epoch|from_unixtime(epoch, yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss)|
+----------+-----------------------------------------+
|1651886168|                      2022-05-06 18:16:08|
+----------+-----------------------------------------+
```

Incorrect approach 2:

```
time_df.select('*',
               F.to_utc_timestamp(F.col('epoch').cast("timestamp"), tz='UTC').alias('timestamp'),
        )
+----------+-------------------+
|     epoch|          timestamp|
+----------+-------------------+
|1651886168|2022-05-06 18:16:08|
+----------+-------------------+
```

Incorrect approach 3:

```
time_df = time_df.select('*',
               F.to_utc_timestamp(F.col('epoch').cast("timestamp"), tz='UTC').alias('timestamp'))
time_df.select('*',
               F.from_utc_timestamp(F.col('timestamp'), tz='UTC').alias('timestamp2'),
).show()

+----------+-------------------+-------------------+
|     epoch|          timestamp|         timestamp2|
+----------+-------------------+-------------------+
|1651886168|2022-05-06 18:16:08|2022-05-06 18:16:08|
+----------+-------------------+-------------------+
```

Your help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: try checking your session's timezone (`"spark.sql.session.timeZone"`). it is possible that spark is adding the offset based on that. usually, the default tz is UTC and all timestamps are converted to that.

Comment: Thank you @samkart. Do you know how can I switch to UTC before conversion and switch back to its original setting after I'm done?

Comment: you can set it to blank in most cases which resets to default

Comment: Thank you @samkart. I will post my answer inspired by your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @samkart for the comment. The following worked for me.

```
# set the session's timezone to UTC
timezone = spark.conf.get("spark.sql.session.timeZone")
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.session.timeZone", "UTC")

# convert unix epoch to time in UTC
time_df.select('*', F.from_unixtime(F.col('epoch'))).show()

# set the session's timezone back
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.session.timeZone", timezone)
```

```
+----------+-----------------------------------------+
|     epoch|from_unixtime(epoch, yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss)|
+----------+-----------------------------------------+
|1651886168|                      2022-05-07 01:16:08|
+----------+-----------------------------------------+
```